# Getting more than 20 Facebook search results?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to search for nearby locations using the iOS Facebook Connect SDK. It successfully returns 20 nearby places, however I want it to return more than 20. I am currently using these parameters:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"place", @"type",
                                       centerString, @"center",
                                       @"1000", @"distance",
```

I have tried adding a "limit" parameter and setting it to something like 50, however I still get back the same array of 20 places. I tried playing with offset as well, and have noticed no difference. Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is the limitation from server side. 
I never use Facebook connection SDK before. 
But it maybe the same story as what I meet in Google Places API

When I want to use Google Places to return all the results, I notice in the documentation there is a limitation for 20 return results:
(http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches)

> Zero or more  elements, each containing information about a
>   single establishment. See Place Search Results for information about
>   these results. The Places API returns up to 20 establishment results.
>   Additionally, political  results, or streets, may be returned
>   which serve to identify the area of the request.

Hope this can help.